# calculating values in dynamically added inputs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic

I'm trying to build a utility bill calculator that allows for the user to dynamically add additional lines. each line will have 3 fields: wattage, hours used per day, and the total of wattage*hours. everything works fine on the first line, but when I try to dynamically add additional lines, my code still works with the first product and gives me a NaN. ideally once they're done adding rows, I would sum the total kilowatt hours at the bottom. Pasted below is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxField = 30; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var fieldHTML = '<div>Wattage: <input type="text"  name="field_wattage" value="300" size=4 maxlength="4" onchange="product()"> Hours Per Day Used: <select name="field_hour" onchange="product()"><option value="01"> 01</option><option value="02"> 02</option><option value="03"> 03</option><option value="04"> 04</option><option value="05"> 05</option><option value="06"> 06</option><option value="07"> 07</option><option value="08"> 08</option><option value="09"> 09</option><option value="10"> 10</option><option value="11"> 11</option><option value="12"> 12</option><option value="13"> 13</option><option value="14"> 14</option><option value="15"> 15</option><option value="16"> 16</option><option value="17"> 17</option><option value="18"> 18</option><option value="19"> 19</option><option value="20"> 20</option><option value="21"> 21</option><option value="22"> 22</option><option value="23"> 23</option><option value="24"> 24</option></select> Daily Wattage: <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="dailyproduct" NAME="result" VALUE=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"> Remove Line</a></div>'; //New input field html 
var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
$(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
        // Add field html
    }
});
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
});
});
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function product()
      {

         var num1 = document.myform.field_wattage.value;
         var num2 = document.myform.field_hour.value;
         var myproduct = parseInt(num1) * parseInt(num2);
         document.getElementById('dailyproduct').value = myproduct;

      }
    </script>
<?php


echo "<br>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<br>";
$dateStart = mktime(0, 0, 0, 03, 01);
$dateEnd = mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 31);

if (time() < $dateEnd && time() > $dateStart)
// show stuff
echo "You are in Peak Hours";
else
echo "You are in Off Peak Hours";


?>
<body>
<FORM NAME="myform">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div>
    Wattage: 
    <input type="text" name="field_wattage" value="300" size=4 maxlength="4" onchange="product()">
    </select> Hours Per Day Used: 
    <select name="field_hour" onchange="product()"/>
    <option value="01"> 01</option>
    <option value="02"> 02</option>
    <option value="03"> 03</option>
    <option value="04"> 04</option>
    <option value="05"> 05</option>
    <option value="06"> 06</option>
    <option value="07"> 07</option>
    <option value="08"> 08</option>
    <option value="09"> 09</option>
    <option value="10"> 10</option>
    <option value="11"> 11</option>
    <option value="12"> 12</option>
    <option value="13"> 13</option>
    <option value="14"> 14</option>
    <option value="15"> 15</option>
    <option value="16"> 16</option>
    <option value="17"> 17</option>
    <option value="18"> 18</option>
    <option value="19"> 19</option>
    <option value="20"> 20</option>
    <option value="21"> 21</option>
    <option value="22"> 22</option>
    <option value="23"> 23</option>
    <option value="24"> 24</option>
    </select>
    Daily Wattage: 
    <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="dailyproduct" NAME="dailyproduct" VALUE=""/>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="=" onClick="product()"/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"> Add Line</a>
</div>
</div>
</FORM>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've searched on here all morning and haven't found anything that quite describes my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is with the line `document.myform.field_wattage.value;`. Once you have more than one line on your page `document.myform.field_wattage` returns multiple items, so you can't get a value from it. You should learn how to use your browser's debugger as this was pretty simple to find.

Comment: As dave said, you have two inputs with a name of *field_wattage*, therefore *document.myform.field_wattage* returns an HTMLCollection of the two inputs. Collections don't have a *value* property, so *num1* is set to *undefined*. When used to calculate *myproduct*, the result is *NaN*.

Comment: There is also an orphan *</select>* closing tag with no opening tag.

Comment: What should I do to get around that then? is it possible to change the field_wattage/field_hour to an array and get it to work with some iterative loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a working example below. As I stated in the comments, you are referencing fields by name, and that doesn't work when there are fields named the same on the page.

To solve in a more modern way, you should use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events) and determine which fields to update within the event. In the example, I have written one event to handle the `select` and `input` changes, then I use jQuery's [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to help me find the fields that need to be updated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maxField = 30; //Input fields increment limitation
  var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
  var fieldHTML = '<div>Wattage: <input type="text"  name="field_wattage" value="300" size=4 maxlength="4"> Hours Per Day Used: <select name="field_hour"><option value="01"> 01</option><option value="02"> 02</option><option value="03"> 03</option><option value="04"> 04</option><option value="05"> 05</option><option value="06"> 06</option><option value="07"> 07</option><option value="08"> 08</option><option value="09"> 09</option><option value="10"> 10</option><option value="11"> 11</option><option value="12"> 12</option><option value="13"> 13</option><option value="14"> 14</option><option value="15"> 15</option><option value="16"> 16</option><option value="17"> 17</option><option value="18"> 18</option><option value="19"> 19</option><option value="20"> 20</option><option value="21"> 21</option><option value="22"> 22</option><option value="23"> 23</option><option value="24"> 24</option></select> Daily Wattage: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="dailyproduct" VALUE=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"> Remove Line</a></div>'; //New input field html 
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
  $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
      x++; //Increment field counter
      $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
      // Add field html
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
  });
});

$(".field_wrapper").on("change", "input,select", function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest("div");
  var num1 = parent.find('[name="field_wattage"]').val();
  var num2 = parent.find('[name="field_hour"]').val();
  var dailyproduct = parent.find('[name="dailyproduct"]');
  var myproduct = parseInt(num1) * parseInt(num2);
  dailyproduct.val(myproduct);
  getTotal();
});

function getTotal() {
 var total = 0;
 $('[name="dailyproduct"]').each(function() {
   total += (parseInt(this.value, 0) || 0);
 });
 $("#total").val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field_wrapper">
  <div>
    Wattage: 
    <input type="text" name="field_wattage" value="300" size=4 maxlength="4" />
    Hours Per Day Used: 
    <select name="field_hour">
      <option value="01"> 01</option>
      <option value="02"> 02</option>
      <option value="03"> 03</option>
      <option value="04"> 04</option>
      <option value="05"> 05</option>
      <option value="06"> 06</option>
      <option value="07"> 07</option>
      <option value="08"> 08</option>
      <option value="09"> 09</option>
      <option value="10"> 10</option>
      <option value="11"> 11</option>
      <option value="12"> 12</option>
      <option value="13"> 13</option>
      <option value="14"> 14</option>
      <option value="15"> 15</option>
      <option value="16"> 16</option>
      <option value="17"> 17</option>
      <option value="18"> 18</option>
      <option value="19"> 19</option>
      <option value="20"> 20</option>
      <option value="21"> 21</option>
      <option value="22"> 22</option>
      <option value="23"> 23</option>
      <option value="24"> 24</option>
    </select>
    Daily Wattage: 
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="dailyproduct" VALUE=""/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"> Add Line</a>
  </div>
</div>

<label>
  Total:
  <input id="total" />
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer Dave.

just so I understand:

we're adding an onchange event, and then searching by fieldname within the latest div and then assigning the value through .val?

shouldn't I be able to do the same thing at the end of the page to get my total wattages with a sum?